# Returning plain-text/non-JSON data from .net core API

Tags: .net, json, angular, rest, .net-core

At my current workplace, we usually have our APIs return JSON objects for 90% of the cases, however certain simpler endpoints are currently returning simple plain text, example endpoints are:

- `GET ../entity/lastChange` (returns the last updated dateTime for a particular entity type) - returns `"2019-08-02 11:26:32.341817-07:00"`
- `GET ../css?platform=android` (returns CSS content that is used for dynamic styling based on platform) - returns `".my-class { color: red; }"`

I've had a read of the REST guidelines (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and could not really find any information regarding this. I also had a read of a few posts on the same topic, but those seem to focus on whether we can, not whether we should.

What I'm thinking of is that often it is convenient to get the result as a string/plain-text directly, however that will often lead to issues down the track around brittle architecture or certain clients (e.g. Angular HttpClient expecting valid JSON objects to be returned from all endpoints). What I'm thinking of is adding a generic `SimplApiResult<T> { public T Result { get; set; } }` class that can be re-used across multiple APIs to wrap basic response types.

### Summary

Should simple RESTful endpoints return plain text where appropriate or simple JSON structures, e.g.:

- Plain text `"2019-08-02 11:26:32.341817-07:00"`
- Simple json `{ "result": "2019-08-02 11:26:32.341817-07:00" }`

Answer (score 1):

Your response header should either have:

```
"Content-Type: application/json"
```

or

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

This tells the client what type it should be expecting.

Angular `HttpClient()` will take in plain text (`string`) and you must parse the JSON (`JSON.parse()`), but `HttpClient<T>()` expects JSON so it can map to a Type/Interface/Class. I believe both of the methods check  `Content-Type` in the header and will give errors if using the wrong response type.

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, the REST paradigm is in its core about representing *Ressources* by their path (in the URI) and their state or state transitions by operating on them with *Verbs* (GET, POST, DELETE, ...). By its idea REST is indifferent to what the type of this resources is. Current Web APIs often use JSON (like default serializer in .NET Core is for JSON, which can be changed) but that's just convention. It's completelly RESTful to use any content type (JSON, plain text, XML, jpg, binary, ...) if it is a resource with a state.